# HTML load pathID from array randomly for SRC path

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

i am trying to make the webpage load random youtube video from array, this is what i am trying tell you

```
String[] pathID = {"ONjesT18bVQ","ONjesT18bVQ","ONjesT18bVQ"};

<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
<iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"
src="https://youtube.com/embed/"+ pathID[get random number here]+"autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1">
</iframe>
</div>
```

this is what i want it to look like, pathID is loaded from array, but i dont know how to do that in HTMl, i don't have much experience in html

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set the `src` of the `iframe` with the random youtube id instead:

**JS**

```
var paths = ["ONjesT18bVQ","ONjesT18bVQ","ONjesT18bVQ"]; //array of ids

var item = paths[Math.floor(Math.random()*paths.length)]; //random

document.getElementById("video").src = "https://youtube.com/embed/"+item+"?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1" //set id
```

**HTML**

```
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
   <iframe id="video" frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
 </div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bvexrnqd/1/)

Comment: Hey i am having trouble running the code
heres the [error](http://i.imgur.com/mstnOPm.png), i already added the missing >but still it does not load

Comment: @user4335407 load  the JS files after the html

Comment: oh lol, made your code to function and used `<body onload="sFunction()">`

Comment: It works but for some reason it does not load theses `autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1` i dont know why

Comment: OHH `/autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1` should be `?autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1` thanks it works <3

Comment: yeah sorry, i forgot it was a `?` and i just added a `/`

Answer (score 0):

it's no JS :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var videoLinks = ["ONjesT18bVQ","ONjesT18bVQ","ONjesT18bVQ"],
    url = '',
    l = videoLinks.length,
    headerBlock = '<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%"><iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%"src="https://youtube.com/embed/',
    footerBlock = '"autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1"></iframe></div>',
    i;

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

for (i=0; i<l; i++){
  document.writeln( headerBlock + videoLinks[getRandomInt(0,l)] + footerBlock );
}
</script>
```